# SQL SERVER loop through and remove space from value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Conceptually, this is easy. But I'm rather new to T-SQL and am having trouble finding the correct syntax.

I uploaded a .csv file into a SQL Server table which contains two columns: CODE | COUNTRY

Unfortunately, the CODE column values have 2 char and a trailing space. I need to remove the space from each code value.

e.g.,  'AD ' should be 'AD' and so on ...

Here's the pseudocode:

```
variable X = select all from Country table
foreach (row in X)
{
   var c = rtrim(row.code);

   update code = c;
}
```

Right now, I don't have an id column. Do I need to make an id column in my table to make this work?

I know that I can do this by using c# and linq. But that seems like overkill. Is there a straightforward way to do this using a t-sql query?

Tips/help appreciated ... thanks!

Comment: As general advice, you shouldn't be thinking of looping when you approach a problem with SQL. You should first try to frame the goal in terms of the entire *set* of rows - SQL is a set-based language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run this update and you will update code for all lines.

```
UPDATE Country set code = RTRIM(code)
```

Comment: ahhhhhhh, so easy if you know it! i spent too much time on this. arghhh. thanks a bunch. thanks to @Darren also. I'm guessing nozari answered first so I'll accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple for an update statement.

```
UPDATE Country SET Code = RTRIM(Code)
```